How to intercept concurrent login in Jenkins?
I’m looking for a way to prevent concurrent logins in Jenkins v2.440.3. Specifically, I would like to implement a restriction where, if an admin user logs in on one browser or tab, Jenkins would either:

Block any new login attempts in other browsers or tabs.
Automatically log out the user from previous sessions if a new login
occurs.

I have tried Concurrent Login plugin in Jenkins. But it is not working properly. Has anyone implemented this feature or found a plugin that handles concurrent login interception in Jenkins? Any guidance or best practices would be appreciated.

What?! An 11 years old plugin with 49 users doesn't work? Shocking!

Actually, the plugin is preventing the same user from logging in on different browsers but allowing login in different tabs of the same browser. However, it is displaying an error message that says, 'The page is not working,' instead of the expected message: 'The user 'admin' is already signed in. Showing the expected message in already successfully singed in page. Please try again later.' Additionally, the 'Intercept Concurrent Login - Activate/Deactivate' checkbox is being automatically unchecked.

I think session timeout is the closest you can get, as explained here:

sessionTimeout is set in minutes; a user will be logged out after this time, no matter what. Default is 30 minutes.


sessionEviction is set in seconds; a user will be logged out after this time if their session is idle. Default is 30 minutes.

